# How can i order my votes by vote count? Django

Tags: python, html, django, count

so i made it that my books will show in my admin but i dont know how to order the books(in the admin) by votes and not by last voted. I found some answers here on overflow but i wasnt able to integrate them by myself. Here are my files:

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Vote

admin.site.register(Vote)
```

apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class SurveyConfig(AppConfig):

    name = 'survey'
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import Vote

class VotingForm(forms.Form):

    chosen_books_options = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=[], label='Book Name', required=False,

                                                     widget=forms.SelectMultiple(

                                                        attrs={

                                                             'class': 'form-control'
                                                         }
                                                     ))
    other_book_name = forms.CharField(label='Other', max_length=100, required=False,
                                      widget=forms.TextInput(
                                        attrs={
                                              'class': 'form-control',
                                              'placeholder': 'Did we miss something?'
                                          }
                                      ))
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        unique_books_names = Vote.objects.order_by('book_name').values_list('book_name', flat=True).distinct()
        self.fields['chosen_books_options'].choices = [(book_name, book_name) for book_name in unique_books_names]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models, transaction

class Vote(models.Model):

    book_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):

        return '%s: %d votes' % (self.book_name, self.count)

    @classmethod

    def bulk_vote(cls, book_names):
        with transaction.atomic():
            for book_name in book_names:
                if len(book_name) == 0:
                    continue
                if Vote.objects.filter(book_name=book_name).exists():

                    Vote.objects.filter(book_name=book_name).update(count=models.F('count') + 1)
                else:
                    Vote.objects.create(book_name=book_name, count=1)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import VotingForm

from .models import Vote

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VotingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            chosen_books_options = form.cleaned_data.get('chosen_books_options', [])
            other_book_name = form.cleaned_data.get('other_book_name', '')
            Vote.bulk_vote(chosen_books_options + [other_book_name])
        message = 'Thank You For Your Contribution!'
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        message = ''
    form = VotingForm()
    return render(request, 'templates/survey.html', {'form': form, 'message': message})
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>       
        .form-control{
          width: 50%;
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" id="thisone">
    <h3>Select which books you'd like us to get started with.</h3>

    <h5>{{ message }}</h5>
    <form action="" method="post">

        {% csrf_token %}

        {{ form.as_p }}

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

    </form>

  </div>

</body>
```

thank you for reading
note: this is not fully my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your admin, you can use the `ordering` attribute like so...

```py
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Vote

class VoteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = ('count',)

admin.site.register(Vote, VoteAdmin)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Sadly nothing has changed when i put the code in....

Comment: Sorry, you've called your field `count`. Answer updated.

Comment: I also tried that one before your new solution. It isnt working either... I dont have to migrate right? If yes there are "no changes detected"... Still a big thanks to you!

Comment: Might be a silly question but have you also made your migrations before trying to migrate?

Comment: If you mean `python manage.py makemigrations` then yes. (Im on windows)

Comment: OK, it's missing the VoteAdmin on the last line. I'll change the answer and hopefully that will sort the issue!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214618/discussion-between-boritobison-and-wayne-lambert).